# Remove a combination of numbers and symbols from a string using the ${VARNAME//pattern/} way

Tags: bash, regular-expression, delete

I am trying to write a script that performs diff on the output of valgrind using two different executables, but the process ID at the start of each line
is littering my diff output. I am trying to remove it using bash commands but can't seem to succeed.

Here's my code so far:

```
VG_MY=$((valgrind --leak-check=full ./executable < inputfile) 2>&1)
VG_MY=${VG_MY//[0-9]/}
```

this remove all digits from VG_MY, same as this:

```
VG_MY="${VG_MY//[[:digit:]]/}"
```

I've tried to add the == parts in many ways but none worked. Closest I've got is:

```
VG_MY="${VG_MY//[==[:digit:]==]/}"
```

Which removes all digits AND '=' from the valgrind output.
I need to figure out what I am missing in order to remove only the numbers enclosed by '=' like so: ==123456== from the valgrind output.

EDIT:
a sample of valgrind output:

```
==94953== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==94953== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==94953== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==94953== Command: ./executable
==94953== 
==94953== 
==94953== HEAP SUMMARY:
==94953==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==94953==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 232 bytes allocated
==94953== 
==94953== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==94953== 
==94953== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==94953== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 8 from 6)
```

Comment: Bash string substitutions are neat, but why do you _insist_ on using them for the purpose? Also, why not pipe the output through `tr`, `sed`, `awk` or any other tool that was created for the task? Since you already use a subshell I don't see why that would be inappropriate. So: `$((valgrind --leak-check=full ./executable < inputfile) 2>&1|tr '[:digit:]' '')` for example ...

Comment: Please show the output of `valgrind`. Not every one has `valgrind` installed.

Comment: Depending on what your input looks like and what `diff` you  have, you may be able to use the `-I` option to `diff` to ignore certain lines completely.

Comment: I just realized that you probably have multiple instances of `== PID ==` in the variable, as valgrind [appears](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.options) to repeat the PID in the output.  Sample input & output would be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks to you all, I'll add a sample of valgrind output.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I asked about Bash string substitutions because they are what I know, but if you have a different way I'd try it. What you did write doesn't include a '=' anywhere, will it know not to remove numbers not enclosed by '='? Also, I do want the valgrind output as it is at first in order to print it to a file, and only later to remove the process id's. It is not critical but if there is a way I preffer it.

Comment: @YekhezkelYovel: someone already suggested a method with `sed` now, so nothing to add from my end. I just think that while string substitutions are a powerful tool, this isn't what they were created for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `ksh` or `bash -O extglob` (or after `shopt -s extglob` in a `bash` script) or `zsh -o kshglob` (or after `set -o kshglob` in a `zsh` script):

```
VG_MY=${VG_MY//+(=)+([0-9])+(=)/}
```

The `+(...)` is a ksh extended glob similar to the `+` extended regexp operator. `+(x)` matches on one or more `x`s.

So the above removes all sequences of one or more `=`s followed by one or more decimal digits followed by one or more `=`s like `sed -E 's/=+[0-9]+=+//g'`¹ would.

Not that it would fail to remove  `456==` inside `==123====456==` since the first replacement would remove `==123====` leaving something that doesn't match the pattern. To be able to remove those, you could change it to:

```
VG_MY=${VG_MY//+(=)[0-9]*([0-9=])=/}
```

(like `sed -E 's/=+[0-9][0-9=]*=//g'`)

With `zsh`'s own extended globs (`zsh -o extendedglob`): `#` is the equivalent of ERE `*` and `##` of ERE `+` (and `(#c1,3)` of `{1,3}`). So, there you can do:

```
set -o extendedglob
VG_MY=${VG_MY//=##[0-9]##=##/}
```

---

¹ Note that while several `sed` implementations support `-E` for extended regexps, it's not standard yet, and you can occasionally find some implementations that don't support  it. With those, you can skip `-E` and use `\{1,\}` as the BRE replacement for `+` (or use `==*` instead of `=+`).

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the VG_MY=${VG_MY//+(=)+([0-9])+(=)/} code but it didn't work, even when I added "bash -O extglob" to the script file. I am using the .sh extention and execute the script using double click from gnome, I guess I am using bash.

Comment: @YekhezkelYovel, you'd need `#! /bin/bash -` at the start of the script. Better to use the `.bash` extension if it's a bash script and not a sh script, and use `shopt -s extglob` within the script to enabled the option.

Answer (score 4):

Just delete the `==94953==` at the beginning of each line before comparing the outputs:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./executable1 <inputfile 2>&1 | sed 's/^==[0-9]*== //' >output1
valgrind --leak-check=full ./executable2 <inputfile 2>&1 | sed 's/^==[0-9]*== //' >output2

diff -u output1 output2
```

Alternatively, which allows you to save the unmodified output and only modify it when running the `diff`,

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./executable1 <inputfile >output1 2>&1
valgrind --leak-check=full ./executable2 <inputfile >output2 2>&1

diff -u <( sed 's/^==[0-9]*== //' <output1 ) <( sed 's/^==[0-9]*== //' <output2 )
```

Comment: Thanks but I preffer to get the valgrind output as it is and print it to file before I remove the pid.

Comment: @YekhezkelYovel See updated answer.

Comment: @YekhezkelYovel: the PID is really pointless information _unless_ you plan on attaching a debugger to the process _while_ it's still running.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I only need it because my output looks better with it. I know I could work on it to liik better but since there are solutions...